# How to load XML children elements from inside another xml file

Tags: xml

I have 3 xml files:

main.xml:

```
<page>
 <title>main page</title>
 <elements></elements>
 <templates></templates>
</page>
```

elements.xml:

```
<elements>
 <element_1>element 1</element_1>    
 <element_2>element 2</element_2>
</elements>
```

templates.xml:

```
<templates>
 <template_1>template 1</template_1>    
 <template_2>template 2</template_2>
</templates>
```

Is it possible to load main.xml and see all `<elements>` of elements.xml inside the `<elements></elements>` node of main.xml and all `<templates>` of templates.xml inside the `<templates></templates>` node of main.xml?

So at the end, main.xml would output like this:

```
<page>
 <title>main page</title>
 <elements>
  <element_1>element 1</element_1>    
  <element_2>element 2</element_2>
 </elements>
 <templates>
  <template_1>template 1</template_1>    
  <template_2>template 2</template_2>
 </templates>
</page>
```

Should i use a xsl file? Can you please give me an example of how it would work?

I like to avoid using a server side language, but if that's strictly nessecary, I'll be using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over you main file, you could just use [XInclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) and then use parsers and processors that are aware of XInclude.

Otherwise, XSLT may include secondary source documents using the [document()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) function. The following stylesheet should do what you seek:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="elements">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('elements.xml')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="templates">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('templates.xml')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. I went with `document()` and it works like a charm. Thanks again.